# Como crear dimensiones para diferentes tamaños de pantallas en android estudio versión 3.3?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, activity

He creado dos dimensiones de  pantalla para 7" de (1024 × 600) y (800 × 1280)
Pero al tratar de emular me sale un error de dimensión no valida podrían ayudarme a que se debe esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para crear dimensiones para diferentes tamaños de pantalla el procedimiento es el siguiente:

Colocate en la vista "`Android`" luego ve al siguiente directorio `res/values`. (Es basicamente el que muestras en pantalla en tu pregunta), luego, clic derecho sobre `dimens` luego `new > Values resource file`.

- Acá te saldrá la ventana de `New Resource File`.
- En el campo `File name`: coloca `dimens` (Tal cual como esta escrito).
- En `Source set : main`
- En `Directory name: values`
- Luego en la sección de la lista "`Available qualifiers`" selecciona "`Size`" Seguidamente clic en el boton "`>>`"

Te pedirá que selecciones el tamaño de pantalla, estas están clasificadas en:

- Small
- Normal
- Large
- X-Large

Seleccionas la que necesites y luego le das clic al botón "`OK`", después repetirás este mismo procedimiento para las densidades de pantallas que necesites según tus requerimientos.

Por ultimo creas las densidades en cada uno de estos archivos.

**Importante:** si en `dimens.xml` tienes por ejemplo:

```
<dimen name="espacio_de_texto_del_titulo">15dp</dimen>
```

En `dimens.xml (large)` debes colocar el mismo nombre, unicamente modificando su valor así:

```
<dimen name="espacio_de_texto_del_titulo">25dp</dimen>
```

Ya que `Android Studio` por defecto buscara el tipo de archivo que necesite según la densidad o tamaño de pantalla en la que se intente correr la aplicación, y en caso que intente buscar el mismo nombre de `dimens.xml` en `dimens.xml (large)` y no coincidan, te mandará un error de que no encuentra la dimensión especificada o otro tipo de error, que quizás pueda ser lo que te esta pasando.

Para mas información acerca de soporte a pantallas:

[Descripción General de la compatibilidad de pantallas](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support?hl=es-419)