# ¿Que layout de android uso para adaptar a diferentes pulgadas?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, layout

Estoy diseñando una aplicación android en android studio y me encuentro en la posición de crear un layout para por ejemplo un log in pero mi pantalla de ejemplo es una 5', en el momento en que este xml lo ejecute en un dispositivo de por ejemplo 6.3' en que layout se mantendria la relacion de tamaño y distancia entre objetos?

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow Adria. Acá tienes una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/232902/89811) que puede ayudarte con eso y un enlace a la documentación oficial referente al tema. Te recomiendo realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que conozcas mejor el sitio.

Comment: Intenta diseñar tus layout lo mas responsive posible. Esto lo puedes lograr siguiendo las características desde la documentación.
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes